# Indicator changes to "2 hours ago" no matter when it was actually posted

Tags: support, status-completed, timestamps

Whenever I look at a question on Stack Overflow, once I spend maybe 30 seconds on that page, or sometimes even if I click edit, the box where it says "posted 10 minutes ago", will automatically switch to "posted 2 hours ago", no matter when it was actually posted.

It seems to happen rather randomly, but it happens on both my laptop and my desktop, which both use Google Chrome.

Is anybody else experiencing something like this?

[image]

This actually happened to this question right as I was about to add another comment.

Another Edit: Now when I refresh the page, it says "asked 14 minutes ago"

Comment: Amazing..Can you post screenshots of posts with links?

Comment: Please hover that text to see the full date, and let us know if that matches that "2 hours ago"?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Of course now that I posted something about it and I'm waiting for a screencap, it hasn't happened again yet. I'll post a screencap and answer Arjan 's question when it happens again.

Comment: Is your system clock wrong by any chance?

Comment: Smart, @balpha! Or maybe the time zone? (I have had zillion users showing an Amsterdam time, but actually some other timezone, or a wrong daylight saving time setting, hence their clock being off many hours without seeing that.)

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Posting picture in a minute.

Comment: @Arjan the picture I posted shows the date it says it was.

Comment: Ah, then balha is probably right. The times are updated by JavaScript. The tooltip shows you're getting the correct time from the server, in `<span title="2012-06-17 09:28:57Z" class="relativetime">14 mins ago</span>`. Then, when the JavaScript kicks in, something goes wrong.

Comment: So, if you know how to use Console, what's the output of `new Date()`

Comment: Or: does the output of the following look okay? http://jsbin.com/umimib

Comment: @Arjan That link says I'm in (Pacific Daylight Time, but it has the correct time. (Sun Jun 17 2012 05:16:39)

Comment: So, @Austin, the time *looks* right for where you are, but you're saying you're actually in a different time zone? Then some settings in your computer(s) are wrong, or you're getting the wrong time from some network device you're synchronizing the time with? And: is the timestamp not showing some additional info as well? Like I get an additional `GMT+0200 (CEST)` in my `Sun Jun 17 2012 12:20:08 GMT+0200 (CEST)`. If the format on your computer is different then Chrome is doing something odd...

Comment: (Just to explain a bit more: I could change my Amsterdam time zone to Pacific Daylight Time, and then adjust my clock to still show `12:22` right now. That would surely mess up all sort of JavaScript date calculations though.)

Comment: (@balpha, only in case a wrong time or time zone might interfere with the global network login: maybe http://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help might like some additional test then?)

Comment: Ah, and just curious: when you hover your name in the top bar, you get a dropdown that shows "UTC time 10:37". That time is updated every minute too. If you leave it open, does it change into something wrong too? Or does it just add a minute?

Comment: @Arjan It seems to just add a minute. Left it alone for 5 minutes and all it did was add a minute, no funny business.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Arjan No, it still does it unfortunately. But it's not really a big deal.

Comment: So, are you sure your time zone is okay? (I did not understand your comment about what http://jsbin.com/umimib showed you.)

Comment: @Arjan My timezone says CST, which is where I am, so that's correct. It doesn't say Pacific Daylight Time anymore like it used to, and I haven't changed anything.

Comment: Still seeing this? Then what does http://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help give you? It now also seems to check time issues. (In the iframe below "Communication with stackauth.com")

Comment: ...and I just [learned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144968/how-does-chat-determine-what-timezone-im-using-and-how-can-i-correct-that) about http://time.is/ Might be useful too!

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated, your computer's system clock is likely wrong.

Comment: It happens on my laptop, and my desktop though.

Comment: try a different web browser, one you don't normally use. If the problem persists, it is your clock. If it does not, then it is something about your custom browser configuration.