# How does chat determine what timezone I'm using — and how can I correct that?

Tags: support, chat

When I last reinstalled Windows, the computer for some reason decided that my clock was set on the local time... on the west coast of America. So while my wall clock said it was half past six and my taskbar clock said it was half past six, http://time.is still claimed my clock was eight hours ahead.

After fixing this timezone snafu, I noticed however that chat.SE still thinks I live on the west coast.

[image]

This bug persists reloading and goes across multiple rooms. Opening chat in an incognito view, however, shows me using my timezone.

How can I reassure chat.SE that I do, in fact, enjoy the advantages of living in the CEST (Correct Earth Summer Timezone) timezone?

Comment: Nice site, http://time.is/ ! That will be useful. That said: nowadays there's also a time check below "Communication with stackauth.com" at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help Does that give you any clue?

Comment: @Arjan "Time - ok"

Comment: Sorry, do you mean Incognito fixes the bug or doesn't?

Comment: @minitech Hope this is clearer now

Comment: Did you open chat in a new, non-incognito tab and see if it persists? I'm pretty sure that Chrome tab processes don't recognise changes in the system timezone (they use whatever was set when they were created), at least on Windows, but it's possible I'm misremembering.

Comment: @TimStone Yes I have. This very screenshot was in a new tab.

Comment: @TLama I'm sorry :) You probably want to read up on free-handed circles and how they're sort of a cultural thing here on Meta. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/13992

Comment: @badp, ah, good to know :-)

Answer (score 4):

The problem's on Google Chrome's part. The timezone information is polled only once per Chrome sub-process. Opening new tabs by middle-clicking links creates new tabs *inside that very same process* and thus the timezone information remains outdated for those tabs as well.

The solution is creating a new tab *in a new sub-process* through the "New tab" button. Timezone information will be then up-to-date.