# Review close votes: following question link sometimes crashes chrome

Tags: bug, review, google-chrome

This is somewhat related to the following question, except that this is more than two years later (and many Chrome versions later):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60984/random-crashes-in-google-chrome-5-0-375-126

Since we've all done a great job getting rid of low quality posts I started doing the close vote reviews. This is when I started experiencing tab crashes and from what I can tell, it happens *sometimes* when I click on a question link on the review page itself, like the one below:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/582548

Not sure if it helps, but although it crashes all the Stack Overflow tabs that are open, the Meta tabs stay unharmed; apparently this is due to how Chrome groups tabs of the same site together in a single process.

I have no extension installed. Chrome 21.0.1180.82 (Mac OS X 10.7.4)

I reported this before, but after disabling the keyboard shortcut extension it didn't happen anymore so I removed the question and can't find it anymore :(

Comment: As an aside: I assume you opened all SE tabs by clicking through from some other SE tab? That makes Chrome run those tabs [in the same process/sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144968/how-does-chat-determine-what-timezone-im-using-and-how-can-i-correct-that/144979#144979). Hence: if the process halts, all those tabs are closed. Opening a new tab and going to stackoverflow.com by typing its URL (or by using some bookmark) creates a new sandbox.

Comment: (No issue for that link in my Chrome 21.0.1180.82 on Mac OS X 10.8.)

Comment: @Arjan thanks for that explanation, I was not aware of how Chrome "groups" multiple tabs together like that. As for reproducing the issue, my title states "sometimes", the mentioned review page was just where the crash occurs, when it does.

Comment: @Arjan yes of course, done!