# UTC time in Account-Popup is off by one hour

Tags: support

In the nice dropdown from the logged in username, at the bottom we find `UTC time`. This time is wrong: it doesn't take DST (Daylight Saving Time) into account. In my timezone (GMT+2, DST in effect), it's one hour off. It's not critical I suppose, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your system clock? It's fine for me.

Comment: The problem is not my system clock. It's not including DST in determining the UTC time - I suppose it's done client side, so derived from the local time @ the client.

Comment: UTC time doesn't take DST into account.

Comment: @ChrisF: well, that's what I said ...

Comment: For me the drop down says (right now) 8:57 which is UTC time. We're on DST in the UK and the "real" time is 9:57. So everything's working correctly.

Comment: As an aside: nowadays the time is loaded from the server; see [UTC time is wrong when local computer settings are wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83151/utc-time-is-wrong-when-local-computer-settings-are-wrong/83167#83167).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First of all, you should be aware that UTC is *not supposed to* take DST into account. Individual time zones frequently do, but not the reference time. If your local time zone is currently in DST, the UTC time will be extra hour off of your usual GMT offset.

Second, if there is a problem, it's probably on your end. Technologically, that clock is your computers responsibility, not SE's. Rather than being generated by the server as static content, the content of the clock in the dropdown is manged by Javascript on the client side (in your browser) based on YOUR systems clock. If your clock settings are wacked it isn't going to work.

If the clock really isn't showing the correct UTC time, I suggest you check your own OS and BIOS clock settings. You probably have a miss-match and are DOUBLE accounting for DST yourself -- one system correcting the other. Although it might display correctly in your OS due to a duplicated correction (or straight up the wrong time zone), the system clock is probably not set correctly. A common issue is being set to a time zone that doesn't use DST, but is an extra hour off from your correct one so the clock looks correct, but doesn't know that DST is being accounted for.

Comment: Also, even GMT doesn't take DST into account. GMT + DST = [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time)

Answer (score 1):

UTC is supposed to be a universal time, free of national/regional/political considerations (national borders, daylight saving times, etc.) and not connected to the local time in any specific country.

Comment: That might be true, but *this implementation* is connected to the local time settings of the client.

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby Ah, sorry, didn't know that.